# How can I display data from object in angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have an issue with displaying data from API response. The data that I receive are objects in the object. I tried to display data by `JSON.striginfy` but the data isn't clear.

**This data I receive from API:**

[image]

**JSON:**

> {"102":{"173":"AX","175":"ZX","179":"Xantia","183":"XM","186":"Evasion","189":"C3","191":"Saxo","193":"Jumpy","194":"Berlingo","196":"Xsara","200":"C15","204":"Jumper","206":"C8","208":"C5","216":"C2","218":"C4","222":"C1","224":"C6","233":"C-Crosser","241":"Nemo","5007":"DS3","10194":"DS4","15270":"DS5","15382":"C-Zero","15411":"C-Elysée","16100":"SpaceTourer","16536":"MODEL","16693":"Berlingo Electric"},"103":{"244":"Tico","245":"Nexia","246":"Espero","247":"Racer","248":"Evanda","249":"Kalos","250":"Nubira","252":"Leganza","254":"Lanos","255":"Lublin 3","256":"Matiz","257":"Korando","259":"Musso","262":"Chairman","263":"Tacuma","264":"Matiz II","265":"Lanos II","1997":"FSO","2001":"Lublin II","16537":"MODEL"},"104":{"266":"Cinquecento","267":"Punto","269":"Bravo","271":"Brava","273":"Coupé","274":"Barchetta","275":"Ulysse","277":"Palio","278":"Multipla","281":"Croma","283":"Tempra","289":"Ducato","290":"Tipo","292":"Uno","294":"Panda","295":"Marea","300":"126 P","301":"Dobló","304":"Stilo","308":"Seicento","310":"Idea","312":"Scudo","320":"Grande Punto","326":"Linea","329":"500","331":"Fiorino","333":"Sedici","1987":"Strada","4936":"Punto Evo","4938":"Punto Actual","5011":"500C","5015":"Qubo","5102":"500 C","15202":"Freemont","15274":"Panda Classic","15416":"500L","15509":"500 L","15830":"500X","16124":"124 Spider","16125":"Talento","16195":"Fullback","16538":"MODEL"},"105":{"336":"Fiesta","337":"Focus","339":"Escort","340":"Mondeo","346":"Scorpio","352":"Transit","359":"Sierra","361":"Orion","369":"Ka","370":"Explorer","372":"Fusion","374":"StreetKa","375":"Galaxy","377":"Tourneo","385":"Maverick","392":"Puma","402":"S-MAX","406":"C-MAX","415":"Kuga","2016":"Ranger","15418":"B-MAX","15878":"Mustang","16170":"Edge","16390":"EcoSport","16539":"MODEL","16655":"Grand Tourneo"},"106":{"421":"Civic","422":"Jazz","423":"HR-V","424":"Prelude","425":"Legend","426":"Shuttle","427":"Stream","430":"S2000","432":"CR-V","434":"Accord","439":"Integra","450":"FR-V","456":"City","466":"Insight","5018":"CR-Z","16540":"MODEL","17088":"e"},"107":{"467":"Accent","468":"Lantra","469":"Sonata","471":"H100","472":"Getz","474":"S Coupe","475":"Pony","477":"Coupe","478":"Galloper","480":"H1","486":"Atos","489":"XG","490":"Trajet","494":"Santa Fe","496":"Elantra","497":"Tucson","499":"Matrix","501":"Terracan","508":"Grandeur","515":"i30","520":"i10","522":"ix55","523":"i20","4940":"ix35","5220":"ix20","5222":"Genesis","5280":"Veloster","10198":"i40","15598":"Grand Santa Fe","16171":"Ioniq","16307":"H350","16358":"Kona","16541":"MODEL","16677":"Kona Electric","16678":"Ioniq Electric"},"108":{"525":"Neon","526":"Stratus","527":"Vision","528":"New Yorker","529":"Voyager","531":"PT Cruiser","532":"Grand Voyager","533":"Sebring","536":"Saratoga","537":"Le Baron","539":"Viper","543":"300 M","551":"Crossfire","554":"300 C","16542":"MODEL"},}

**Raw data who I display by `JSON.striginfy`:**

[image]

MY CODE:

**component.ts**

```
vehicleModels;
dataIsReady = false;

 constructor(
    private vehicleService: VehicleService,
  ) { }

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getModels();
}

 public getModels() {
    this.vehicleService.getBrandsModels().subscribe(({ models }) => {
      this.vehicleModels = JSON.stringify(models);
      this.dataIsReady = models;
      console.log(models);
    });
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="dataIsReady">
  <p>{{vehicleModels}}</p>
</div>
```

I expecting displaying this data in component for example:

> 102: 173 - AX, 175 - ZX,
> 103: 244 - Tico, 245 - Nexia

How to correct display this data?

Comment: How exactly do you want to display this object on the template?

Comment: For example 118: 952 - Corsa, 953 - Tigra ...

Comment: Can you paste the json as text in your question so it can be easy to reproduce?

Comment: sure I add json at the top

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do so using the following code on the template by using the *keyvalue* pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of vehicleModels | keyvalue">
    <div>
        <strong>{{obj.key}}:</strong>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let inner of obj.value | keyvalue" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <span>{{inner.key}}</span> -
        <span>{{inner.value}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the Angular JSON pipe.

```
{{vehicleModels | json}}
```

This will not format it exactly how you want it though.

That api data is pretty difficult to deal with, if you have any control over it you could change it to something like this.

```
// these interfaces are probably completely wrongly names, i have no idea what your actual business data is called
interface Make {
  make_id: number
  make_name: string
}

interface Model {
  brand_id: number
  brand_name: string
  makes: Make[]
}

// mock service method -> returns an observable of mock data, i didn't want to set up an actual service
const getBrandsModels$ = (): Observable<Model[]> => {
  return of([
    {
      brand_id: 102,
      brand_name: 'CITOROEN',
      makes: [
        {
          make_id: 173,
          make_name: 'AX'
        },
        {
          make_id: 179,
          make_name: 'Xantia'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      brand_id: 103,
      brand_name: 'DAEWOO',
      makes: [
        {
          make_id: 244,
          make_name: 'Tico'
        },
        {
          make_id: 245,
          make_name: 'Nexia'
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <!-- this is an async pipe, it basically replaces the subscribe stuff -->
    <div *ngIf="(brandModels$ | async) as brandModels">
      <!-- you can put the ngFor on a div but i've chosen to keep them separate so the code is easier to understand -->
      <ng-container *ngFor="let model of brandModels">
        <div>
          {{ model.brand_id }}: {{ model.brand_name }}
          <ng-container *ngFor="let make of model.makes">
            {{ make.make_id }} - {{ make.make_name }}
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DisplayModelsComponent implements OnInit {
  // i'd recommend using an observable and piping it into the template instead of subscribing
  brandModels$: Observable<Model[]>

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // just call for the data and store it in the local variable
    this.brandModels$ = getBrandsModels$()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made the changes what you required.

```
  public formatData(data) {
    const rootKeys = Object.keys(data);
    rootKeys.forEach(item => {
        Object.keys(data[item]);
    });
    this.finalArr = [];
    for (let rootKey in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(rootKey)) {
          this.finalArr.push({key: rootKey, value: []});
          for (let key in data[rootKey]) {
              if (data[rootKey].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this.finalArr[this.finalArr.length - 1].value.push(`${key} - ${data[rootKey][key]}`);
              }
          }
      }
    }
    console.log(this.finalArr);
  }
```

Please see below link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-igxben?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

[image]